# double value returned from a function in static lib is wrong

Tags: c++, c

I have a function c++ like this :

```
extern "C" double compareHistTwoImages()
{
    return 0.999674;
}
```

Then I compile and package it into a static library (Ex: libTest.so)

I have another program that includes this library and has a file.c, in which I use the above function compareHistTwoImages like this:

```
double result = compareHistTwoImages();
printf("--- Result: %f\n", result);
```

However, it doesn't print 0.999674, but print -2066840832.0 instead.
What is the problem here ?

Comment: My first guess would be that the function is declared incorrectly at the point of use, something along the lines of `extern "C" int compareHistTwoImages();`. It's hard telling what could be wrong without a [mcve].

Comment: Which language, C or C++?

Comment: I use both C and C++, the function compareHistTwoImg I write in C++, then I compile it into a static lib. I have used an open-source software written in C, so I'm trying to call my function in that software.

Comment: If you don't have a declaration for the function in the program that calls it, it will default to returning `int`. Make sure you `#include` the header file for it.

Comment: well, I have declared that function in a file.h like this : EXTERNC double compareHistTwoImages(IplImage* img1, IplImage* img2, char* name1, char* name2); . And I include it in the file containing the function above

Comment: @DennisDo Create a [mcve]

Comment: @DennisDo: But that's an entirely different function

Comment: Actually, they are the same function with the same return type and parameters. I just ignore the parameters in the first one, the second one I get from copying from the original code

Comment: Hey guys, there is a weird thing that I couldn't explain. When I change the return type of that function (both in .cpp and .h) from double to int, the program that calls that function return the correct integer value. Therefore, the problem occurs if the return type is double. My temporary solution right now is using it as return type. For the above case, I make the function return 999674. If anyone knows the root cause, please let me know. Tks.